# How to modify Firefox config (pref.js) line using Powershell

Tags: powershell, firefox

Modifying the Mozilla Firefox Pref.js file using PowerShell.

Need to modify the pref.js file line to reflect a new value
(Hence, instead of any value under  user_pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", "*"); to show user_pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", ".abc.com,.abcd.com,.abcde.com") or just add changes after the *

```
$TopDir = "$env:APPDATA\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"
$FileName = 'prefs.js'

$DefaultProfileDir = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $TopDir -Directory).
Where({
    $_.FullName -match '\.default'
    }).FullName

$FullFileName = Join-Path -Path $DefaultProfileDir -ChildPath $FileName

$data = foreach($line in Get-Content $FullFileName)
{
    if($line -contains 'user_pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris".*')
    {
        $line -replace '*' , 'user_pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", ".abc.com,.abcd.com,.abcde.com");'
    }
    else
    {
        $line
    }
}
$data | Set-Content C:\testfolder\test2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Nelson,

I didn't have your line in my FF profile but I got the code to work on another line so you should be able to modify it to work with yours.

```
$TopDir = "G:\Test"
$FileName = 'prefs.js'
$FullFileName = "$TopDir\$FileName"
Clear-Host

$Data = foreach($line in Get-Content $FullFileName) {

  if( ($line.IndexOf('browser.bookmarks.restore_default_bookmarks')) -ne -1)
  {
    If ($line.IndexOf('false') -ne -1) {
      $line = $line.replace( 'false' , 'true')
    }
  }
  $line
}

$data | Set-Content $("$TopDir" + "\prefs2.js")
```

I think your code would be:

```
$TopDir = "$env:APPDATA\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"
$FileName = 'prefs.js'

$DefaultProfileDir = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $TopDir -Directory).
Where({
    $_.FullName -match '\.default'
    }).FullName

$FullFileName = Join-Path -Path $DefaultProfileDir -ChildPath $FileName

$Data = foreach($line in Get-Content $FullFileName) {

  if( ($line.IndexOf('network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris')) -ne -1)
  {
    If ($line.IndexOf('*') -ne -1) {
      $line = $line.replace( '*' , 'abc.com,.abcd.com,.abcde.com')
    }
  }
  $line
}

$data | Set-Content C:\testfolder\test2.txt
```

Note: -contains is designed for lists.
HTH

Comment: Is not working for me after running the script I get no errors, but it doesn't modify the string

Comment: If you have firefox installed the prefs.js file should be under 
C:\Users\[MyUserName]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[RandomStuff].default\prefs.js

Comment: I copied the file to a text directory JIC! Since you're working on C: you may need to add a -Force Parameter to the Set-Content command. You may also have to run PS as Administrator.

Comment: Nelson, out of curiosity, try writing the file to your Documents directory and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I extended it to be easier to use any property

Input

```js
user_pref("foo", "bar")
user_pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", "*")
```

Output

```js
user_pref("foo", "bar")
user_pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", ".abc.com,.abcd.com,.abcde.com")
```

```bsh
$lines = 'user_pref("foo", "bar")', 'user_pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", "*")'

# multi-line regex for readability
$regex = '(?x)    
    (?<prefix>user_pref\()
    (?<name>
        ".*"
    )

    \s*,\s*

    (?<value>
        ".*"
    )
    (?<suffix>.*)    
'

"`ninput:"
$lines

"`noutput:"
$lines | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match $regex) {
        if($matches.name -eq '"network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris"') {
            $_ = '{0}{1}, {2}{3}' -f @(
                $Matches.prefix,
                $Matches.name,
                '".abc.com,.abcd.com,.abcde.com"',
                $Matches.suffix            
            )            
        }
    }

    $_
}
```

Comment: After adding my script with your solution I get  the input-output values looping indefinitely